# Member Variables in Class Get Blown Away When Using std::thread

Tags: linux, c++11, valgrind, stdthread

I have defined a base class using `std::thread`.  For the child class, I perform some initialization of member variables and then start the thread using `m_thread.reset(new std::thread(&MyClass::ThreadMain, this));` where m_thread is a member of MyClass.  The purpose of the class is to read data from a serial port and report to a parent.  The posix message queue handle of the parent is passed to MyClass during initialization before the thread is created.  On running I get exceptions and I see that member variables that were initialized before the thread started appear to be no longer valid using the watch in GDB.

It appears as if the first message on the serial port is received and passed validation in order to get to the `SendToParent` call.  At this call, it appears that I lose the stack.  I tried running cppcheck to see if I have any memory leaks or buffer overflows and found nothing.

```
void MyClass::ThreadMain(void)
{
   ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
   UINT8 buffer[256];
   UINT8 message[256];
   BOOL partialMessage = FALSE;
   UINT8 messageIndex = 0;
   UINT8 payloadLength = 0;

   // read data from the UART
   while(1)
   {
      // the UART is setup to pend until data is available
      bytesRead = read(m_radioFileDescriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
      if (FAIL == bytesRead)
      {
         LOG_SYSTEM_INFO("UART Read interrupted by a system call");
      }
      else if (bytesRead > 0)
      {
         // build the message
         for(ssize_t i = 0 ; i < bytesRead ; i++)
         {
            if (FALSE == partialMessage)
            {
               // have we found the start of the message?
               if(START_BYTE == buffer[i])
               {
                  // start of new message
                  messageIndex = 0;
                  message[messageIndex] = buffer[i];
                  partialMessage = TRUE;
                  messageIndex++;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               // keep building the message until the expected length is reached
               if(LENGTH_POSITION == messageIndex)
               {
                  // capture the expected message length
                  message[messageIndex] = buffer[i];
                  messageIndex++;
                  payloadLength = buffer[i];
               }
               else
               {
                  message[messageIndex] = buffer[i];
                  messageIndex++;

                  // check for expected length and end byte
                  if((messageIndex == payloadLength) && (END_BYTE == buffer[i]))
                  {
                     // this should be a valid message but need to confirm by checking for a valid checksum
                     UINT8 messageChecksum = message[messageIndex - CHKSUM_POS_FROM_END];
                     UINT8 calculatedChecksum = RadioProtocol::Instance().GenerateRadioChecksum(message, (payloadLength - CHKSUM_POS_FROM_END));
                     if (messageChecksum == calculatedChecksum)
                     {
                        SendToParent(message, payloadLength);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        LOG_SYSTEM_ERROR("Checksum FAILURE");
                     }

                     // reset for the next message
                     partialMessage = FALSE;
                     messageIndex = 0;
                  }
                  else if((messageIndex == payloadLength) && (END_BYTE != buffer[i]))
                  {
                     // malformed message - throw out and look for start of next message
                     LOG_SYSTEM_ERROR("Bytes read exceeded expected message length");
                     partialMessage = FALSE;
                     messageIndex = 0;
                  }
               }
            }
         } // end for loop of bytes read on the port
      }
      else
      {
         LOG_SYSTEM_INFO("Read returned 0 bytes which is unexpected");
      }
   }
}

void MyClass::SendToParent(UINT8* pMsg, UINT8 size)
{
   if ((pMsg != NULL) && (m_parentQueueHandle > 0))
   {
      // message is valid - pass up for processing
      MsgQueueMessage msgToSend;

      msgToSend.m_msgHeader = UART_MESSASGE;
      bzero(msgToSend.m_msgData, sizeof(msgToSend.m_msgData));
      for (UINT8 i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         msgToSend.m_msgData[i] = pMsg[i];
      }

      if (FAIL == msgsnd(m_parentQueueHandle, &msgToSend, sizeof(msgToSend), IPC_NOWAIT))
      {
         LOG_SYSTEM_ERROR("FAILED to send message on queue");
      }
   }
}
```

This acts like I am performing a buffer overflow but I just can't see it.  When I set a breakpoint at the line `UINT8 messageChecksum = message[messageIndex - CHKSUM_POS_FROM_END];` all data in the watch window appear valid.  If I step over to the next line then the data, `m_parentQueueHandle` as an example, gets blown away.

This is my first time working with c++11 threads and particularly with c++.  Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably should have teft the Valgrind output in the question.

Comment: Yes.  I originally had Valgrind output but had to remove it because it was not sanitized.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.  I added a bunch of printfs and found that the destructor for the class was being called.  Much further upstreamI had the parent object being created as a local variable and it was going out of scope.  This caused the child to go out of scope but the threads were still running.  I certainly need to clean up the threads in the destructor.

Comment: Usually what you do is, you put all your thread parameters in a `struct`. Then you create it on the heap with `new`. Something like `void* params = new MyStruct(w, x, y, z, ...);`. You will also need to change `ThreadMain(void)` to `ThreadMain(void* params)`. Then, the thread is responsible for casting `params` to a `MyStruct*` and deleting it. That ensures `MyStruct` survives.